# Show that exists a unique $c^\ast\in\mathscr{C}$ such that $\|x_0-c^\ast\|_2=dist(x_0,\mathscr{C})$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Consider $(\mathbb{R}^k,\|.\|_2), \mathscr{C}\subset \mathbb{R}^k$ a non-empty, convex and closed subset and $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^k$. Show that exists a unique $c^\ast\in\mathscr{C}$ such that $\|x_0-c^\ast\|_2=dist(x_0,\mathscr{C})$. Show that $c^\ast$
is characterized by the following two conditions:

1. $c^\ast\in \mathscr{C},$
2. $\langle\,x_0-c^\ast,c-c^\ast\rangle\leq 0$ for all $c\in\mathscr{C}$.

My try:

For the existence of $c^\ast$:

Let a sequence $(c_n)$ in $\mathscr{C}$ such that $\|x_0-c_n\|_2\rightarrow dist(x_0,\mathscr{C})$. I want to show that $(c_n)_n$ is a Cauchy sequence, but I'm having trouble proving it. Also any suggestions about the other proofs would be great!

Comment: Maybe it helps $$||c_n||_2\leq ||x_0||_2+||x_0-c_n||_2$$ so $ c_n $ is convergent, so it's from Cauchy as you want.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

(1) For every positive integer $p$,
$$ \Vert c_{n+p}-c_n\Vert_2 \le \Vert c_{n+p}-x_0\Vert_2+\Vert x_0-c_n\Vert_2 $$
You can let $n$ large enough and then $\Vert c_{n+p}-c_n\Vert_2$ can be small arbitrarily.

(2) You can suppose $\exists c_0$ s.t. $\langle x_0-c^*,c_0-c^*\rangle>0$, and find $c’\in\mathscr{C}$ s.t. $\Vert x_0-c’\Vert_2<\inf\limits_{c\in\mathscr{C}} \Vert x_0-c\Vert_2$.